# Non-symmetric system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

What are non-symmetric system of linear equations? I am unable to find any definition online for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A symmetric linear equation $Ax=b$, has $A$ as a symmetric matrix, i.e $a_{ij}=a_{ji}.$ Non-symmetric is any linear equation that doesn't satisfy this property.

Comment: Thanks for answering.